# delay animation before restarting the activity

Tags: java, android, animation, runnable, postdelayed

I've a GifImageButton view. I want to start its animation and then restart the activity.

The **problem** is that I want the animation to last 3 seconds before restarting the activity.

How can I do it?

**this is my code:**

```
myGifImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.animation);
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
if (intent != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

As I read, the better way is to use a runnable so I tried this but I didn't succeed it:

```
// start the animation
myGifImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.animation);

// delay the animation
mHandler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 3000);

// restart the activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
if (intent != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

so how can I delay the animation before restarting the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yor runnable is incorrect - you are continously reposting the same runnable which does nothing.

Instead try something like this:

```
// start the animation
myGifImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.animation);

// delay the animation
mHandler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    void run() {
       // restart the activity
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       finish();
       if (intent != null) {
           startActivity(intent);
       }
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 3000);
```